# Easier way to add up all the given values of a column in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php

I feel like there must be an easier way to handle this problem; so I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
$reports = array(
    array("Complete Installation", 1),
    array("Register + OSR Install", 0),
    array("OSR + Wire", 0),
    array("OSR Only", 1),
    array("Ground Strap Installation", 2),
    array("Meter Only", 2)
);
```

And I would like to show a percentage out of the total value of the second (well, first, but you know what I mean) column of the `Array`. Right now I'm using a `foreach`, but it seems really redundant and not very efficient:

```
foreach($reports as $report) {
    $total_val += (int)$report[1];
}
foreach($reports as $report) {
    $name = $report[0];
    $val = (int)$report[1];
?>
<tr>
    <td><?=(stripslashes($name));?></td>
    <td><?=($val);?></td>
    <td><?=(($val > 0) ? round(($val / $total_val) * 100, 2) : $val);?></td>
</tr>
```

I feel like there must be a better way to handle that, in-order to get the variable `$total_val = 6;` without re-looping the `Array`. A way to add up all the `$report[1]`'s. Any ideas?

Comment: As a general comment, sub-arrays like that make me uneasy. For non-uniform data you should use associative arrays, e.g. `array('type'=>'Complete Installation', 'value'=>1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run PHP 5.5 it's dead easy:

```
$total = array_sum(array_column($reports, 1));
```

If you don't, then either the `foreach` (there is nothing wrong with it -- on the contrary, simple is good) or some fancy alternatives:

```
// If you go fancy this should be your choice, the others are slightly inferior
$total = array_reduce($reports, function($sum, $r) { return $sum + $r[1]; }, 0);
```

or

```
$total = array_sum(array_map(function($r) { return $r[1]; }, $reports);
```

or

```
$total = 0;
array_walk($reports, function($r) use (&$total) { $total += $r[1]; });
```

Comment: @Barmar: Added that as well :-)

Comment: Thank you kindly sir; unfortunately this server is no where near up to date and I kept getting `unexpected T_FUNCTION` errors due to the lake of support of anonymous functions; but with some tweaking I used `array_reduce`. I will keep note of all of these, again I thank you for the answers.